# .travis.yml file should read from another file a value and use it

Tags: shell, global-variables, travis-ci, file-read, travis-ci-cli

In my [.travis.yml file](https://github.com/joergi/MagPiDownloader/blob/42e719803a90937a001582ae66986d536b285307/.travis.yml) I wanna read which issues is the latest at the moment in my [issue file](https://github.com/joergi/MagPiDownloader/blob/test_travis/issues.txt)

.travis.yml:

```
env:
  global:
    - issues=$(cat "issues.txt");
matrix:
  include:
  - language: bash
    script:
    - bash linux_mac/magpi-issue-downloader.sh -f $issues-4 -l $issues
```

issues file:
[image: issue file: only a 89 is in]

as you see, I wanna run the bash script with something like:

```
- bash linux_mac/magpi-issue-downloader.sh -f 85 -l 89
```

Travis shows in the console that there is no error, but it was not doing it correctly as you can see in the screenshot
[image: .travis screenshot]

The `.travis.yml` is in the same root folder as the `issues.txt` file
[image: folder screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now like this:

```
env:
  global:
    - issue=$(<issues.txt)
matrix:
  include:
  - language: bash
    script:
    - bash linux_mac/magpi-issue-downloader.sh -f $(($issue - 5)) -l $(($issue))
```

this worked for me.